# z/OS Unix System Services BPXBATCH ends with CC=3840

Tags: zos, jcl

My BPXBATCH step is failing and I can't find the specific RC/RSNC described in M&C. For what it's worth, I had the JCL in an HFS dataset and ran USS's submit command.

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Another clue:
My z/OS system will not allow me to sign into my ID in OMVS (3270 mode through ISPF panels), and simultaneously log in to my id in USS's SSH shell. It gives a resource busy error. The sysadmin claims this is not supported, but I suspect it could be made to be supported.

I've tried to find info on messages and codes, but did not see anything for this specific error.

COPYHFS Step

```
//COPYHFS EXEC PGM=BPXBATCH
//STDERR DD SYSOUT=*
//STDOUT DD SYSOUT=*
//STDPARM DD *
SH cp
 -P "RECFM=FB,LRECL=287,BLKSIZE=6027,SPACE=(TRACK,(1,1))"
 /u/woodsmn/SSC.D051721.T200335.S90.CP037
 //\'WOODSMN.SSC.D051721.T200335.S90.CP037\'
/*
```

STDERR DD

```
FSUM1004 Cannot change to directory </u/woodsmn>
```

IEF142I WOODSMNX COPYHFS - STEP WAS EXECUTED - COND CODE 3840 (edited)

Comment: After reading https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=environments-bpxbatch - there seems to be a lot of strange multiplying and dividing of retuncodes with BPXBATCH. In your case it seems the process received a TERM-signal....

Comment: What version of z/OS?  Is this actually an HFS, which is depreciated, or a ZFS?  Are you in a sysplex?  Are you using shared file systems?

Comment: Might be that you are limited on the number of processes your UID may run in parallel. If you are authorized for those commands, try `TSO LU WOODSMN OMVS NORACF`, and look for the value `PROCUSERMAX`. Also try `D OMVS,O` in `SDSF`, and look for the values `MACPROXSYS`, `MAXPROCUSER`.

Comment: Can you change to directory `/u/woodsmn` in a shell session?

Comment: @KevinMcKenzie You're right, it is a ZFS, I think I came back to this after ZFS came out and still kept using the old name.

Comment: @phunsoft Yes I can. I can do it both in SSH and through the ISPF panels.

Comment: Very unusual: Your TSO/MVS userid is *WOODSMN*, but your UNIX home directory is */u/bpracht*. But this doesn't seem to have anything to do with your problem. Can you as your friendly system programmer what the UNIX limit, system wide, and for your userid especially, with respect to processes per user, and open files per user are?

Comment: @phunsoft That should have read /u/woodsmn. My apologies. I'm not authorized to run the operator command, but I didn't see values you mentioned: USER=WOODSMN OMVS INFORMATION ---------------- UID= 0000010795 HOME= /u/bpracht PROGRAM= /bin/sh

Comment: Ask your friendly system programmer why they say it is not supported to run multiple shells in parallel. There might be shops that do not want their users to make use of z/OS UNIX services at all, and that therefore take lot of (nonsense) effort to achieve this. It's rubbish, IHMO. As a matter of fact, you cannot run z/OS without fully enabled z/OS UNIX today. So, don't give up and try to get your problem solved together with system programming at your shop.

Comment: It's definitely common to run OMVS under TSO and have SSH shell sessions active concurrently - I do it all the time. Unless your administrator has some reason for wanting such a thing, most likely there's just a configuration error somewhere. I'd start by checking any login scripts your site might run (.profile and the like). I recall that some of the security products had a way to limit signons by a user to one terminal at a time - possibly something like this is causing your problem.

Comment: @ValerieR Can you speak with my sysadmin please :)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see why you got `FSUM1004 Cannot change to directory </u/woodsmn>`, since you wrote you *can* change to directoy `/u/woodsmn`. So I thought I'd try to reproduce your error, but got different one:

```
cp: FSUM6258 cannot open file "//'Z10411.SSC.D051721.T200335.S90.CP037'": EDC5121I Invalid argument.
```

After I changed `SPACE=(TRACK,(1,1))`to `SPACE=(TRK,(1,1))` the job completed without error.

The job did run under your userid `WOODSMN`, didn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure why there'd be a chdir at all, but maybe it does a chdir when it first mounts the zfs volume. As for the dataset, I don't think it matters too much what it is content wise. The key thing is that it's a traditional  mvs dataset.  Can you sign into omvs via a 3270 panel and ssh into your account at the same time? I'd love it if you could attest to this. I'd say where I work but don't want to embarras them.

Comment: I wanted to write this before, but haven't done obviously. Sorry, **Yes**, I can work with with multiple shell sessions at the same time. One being startet through TSO -> OMVS, and multiples via SSH or telnet. Each session needs to be able to start a couple of preocesses during login processing, and later when you're working in the shell(s).

Comment: No, a `mount` does not initiate a `chdir`. But the shell wants to `chdir` into your home directory upon startup. That might then initiate mounting of your home file system (ZFS, or HFS), *if* the system is setup to *automount* user home file systems. But again, I wonder why your profile (OMVS segment) has `/u/bpracht` as home directory. I would have expected `/u/woodsmn`. Can you `chdir` to `/u/bpracht` from a shell session?

Comment: So the data set is preallocated? I thought ou wanted to `cp` to allocate it because of all the data set allocation parameters `-P RECFM=....`. I did not preallocate, and that is why `cp` complained about `TRACK` being an invalid argument. Those parameters are not used (and obviously not tested) when the data set already exists.

Comment: I try to obscure any identity before posting. Unfortunately, I missed that one bit. I hope you can understand. My OMVS segment has what I would have called /u/woodsmn. I can chdir into /u/woodsmn (my home directory.). In all cases where you saw /u/bpracht, it should have said /u/woodsmn

Comment: Originally, I tried to use cp with -P to allocate a new dataset. Unfornately, I could not get the right level of escaping done in the JCL to support the -P approach. On the advice of someone else, I now pre-create the dataset and copy into it using cp. Overall, my process creates a new dataset each and every time. We rely on HSM to eventually migrate the datasets away.

Comment: It's hard to help you any further without more information about your system's setup with respect to z/OS UNIX System Services. I can offer you to follow up via private email, so that you can send me information about your system without publishing it here for everyone. Contact me at "phun at gmx.ch".

Comment: Thanks, an email is on it's way. Please feel free to edit your comment accordingly if you wish.